# How do I pass a global or process private global by reference to a procedure

Tags: syntax, parameter-passing, intersystems-cache, objectscript

Say I have Caché ObjectScript procedure that expects to receive a by reference array parameter:

```
TotalArray(Arr)
 S Total=0
 S K=""
 F {
  S K=$O(Arr(K))
  Q:K=""

  S Total=Total+Arr(K)
 }
 Q Total
```

I can call that procedure with a regular array by reference with the dot syntax:

```
S A(1)=5
S A(2)=10
W $$TotalArray(.A)
```

But when I try to do it  with a global reference, I get a syntax error with the dot syntax:

```
S ^A(0)=5
S ^A(1)=10
W $$TotalArray(.^A)
```

What is the correct way to pass a global array by reference to an ObjectScript procedure? I also want to be able to pass process private globals (the `^||Array` convention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use it with indirection as Brandon suggested:

```
TotalArray(ArrName)
 S Total=0
 S K=""
 F {
  S K=$O(@ArrName@(K))
  Q:K=""

  S Total=Total+@ArrName@(K)
 }
 Q Total
```

and then you call it like this

```
W $$TotalArray("^A")
```

or even

```
W $$TotalArray("^A(""someIndex"")")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You could either

1. Pass the name of the global, and access it by [Indirection](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_operators#GCOS_operators_indirection), or
2. [MERGE](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_cmerge) the global into a local variable (if it is small enough), and pass that by reference.

Comment: What is the syntax I would use for indirection? I can't MERGE to a local variable because the size can be very large.

Comment: About the syntax for option 1, can you post a version of TotalArray above that does it that way?

Comment: The Documentation linked should explain how to do it. If you would like sample code, I'd recommend contacting InterSystems Support.